Need help writing a simple batch shell script
I'm trying to write a shell script to run on a Windows Server machine; the script will do this:
Create a text string that will be the path and filename, which would be as follows:
fms25_daily_20240922.zip

And I want it to write to D:\Daily:
Here's what I've written and which gets me partway there:
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
     set month=%%j
     set day=%%k
     set year=%%l
)
set datestr=D:\fms25_daily_%year%%month%%day%.zip
powershell Compress-Archive -LiteralPath ‘D:\Daily’ -DestinationPath %datestr%"

When I use the PowerShell command to write to a specific destination, that part works, but I want to use a filename as described above.

what is the problem? ...what is your question?

Maybe try powershell -Command "Compress-Archive -LiteralPath 'D:\Daily' -DestinationPath %datestr%"  -- Your originally posted code contains only a closing double quote; there is no opening double quote.  To @jsotola's point - it's helpful when including any relevant errors asking a specific question e.g. "Why am I getting [this] kind of error message?"   And by the way, welcome to Super User! :-)

Why would you mix PowerShell with batch? So many people do that and come here with questions for banal tasks instead of spending like 1-3 hours to learn PowerShell basics and have basically much easier life.

‘D:\Daily’ why are you using smart quotes? Don't do this.

Adding the double-quote and removing the smart quotes fixed it, thanks.
As to mixing PowerShell & batch: I know nothing about writing shell scripts, so I just found a couple of snippets and put them together. If someone has a more elegant way to do what my clunky script does, I'd certainly like to try it.

OK, so the script runs; I see the ZIP file, until it finishes, and then the file disappears.
I've put the script on 5 servers; 2 of them work fine, but the other 3 display the same behavior. I made sure the destination drive had enough available disk space, and that wasn't the issue. Is this an issue with permissions?
